# Como puedo declarar un valor en multiples clases?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy editando un slider, y resulta que quiero darle un tiempo de velocidad diferente a cada una de las paginas del slider, resulta que la velocidad del slider se inserta al inicio y en una sola area.

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
autoplaySpeed = 60000, 
autoplayTimeout = 60000,
```

esa propiedad afecta a todos los slider, me gustaria que afectara a alguno por individual.

Estoy usando la biblioteca de owl-carousel v2.3.4

La propiedad que quiero dividir para cada slider es la del autoplayspeed.:

```javascript
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var imgItems = $('.slider caption').length; // NUMERO DE SLIDES
        var imgPos = 1;
        var video = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: false,
            autoplay: true,
            items: 1,
            dots: false,
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            autoplaySpeed = 60000,
            utoplayTimeout = 60000,
            nav: true,
            
        })
        
         /* 
        function nextSlider(){
            if(imgPos >= imgItems){
                imgPos = 1;
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplaySpeed',[60000]);
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplayTimeout',[60000]);
            }else if(imgPos >= imgItems){
                imgPos++;
            }
        }
        */
        owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
        $('.play').on('click', function(){  
            owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[60000]);
            myAudio.play();
            
        });
      
        $('.stop').on('click', function(){
            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
            myAudio.pause();
        });
    
        $('.mute').on('click', function(){
            myAudio.muted = true;
    
        });
        $('.unmute').on('click', function(){
            myAudio.muted = false;
    
        });
    
      
            //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio     
            myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            //Objeto con referencia al boton play
            playBtn = document.getElementById("play");
            //Objeto con referencia al boton pause
            pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pause");
            muteBtn = document.getElementById("mute").muted;
        
        
            //Añadiendo funcionalidad a los botones del reproductor
            playBtn.addEventListener("click", play, true);
            pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", pause, true);
            muteBtn.addEventListener("click", muted);
      
    });
```

He intentado crear funciones con if, e intentar obtener la paginación o el index de cada slider, para así saber en qué slider estoy situado y darle propiedades diferentes, pero la biblioteca que estoy usando carece de position, si pudiera acceder a la posición, podría darle un audio diferente a cada slider y tiempo diferente.

También intenté que el slider pasara cuando el audio que estaba reproduciendo se acabara, pero todo llevo a nada, me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar exactamente a establecer un audio por slider, o a que cada slider tenga un tiempo en específico, así podría insertarle música sin preocuparme por el tiempo.
`
Este es el html del slider:

```html
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class ="slide slide1">
                <img src="img/d7e1725b3801fb6cdeb212884c893f79.jpg"/>   
                <div class="caption">COOPERATIVA VEGA REAL
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class= "item">
                <img src=" "/>  
                <div class="caption0" >
                    <video id="myAudio" autoplay controls>
                        <source src="medios/2.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                    </video>
                    </div>
                <span>1 of 100 </span>
            </div>
            <div class ="item">
                <img src=" "/>
                <div class="caption1"><h1>Sincronización</h1>
                <p>Este entrenamiento durara aproximadamente 45 minutos.</p>
                <p>Puede ver su progreso en la parte inferior de la pantalla</p>
                <p>Puede retroceder una pantalla seleccionando el boton "Atras" en la barra de navegacion.</p>
                <p>para continuar, seleccione el boton de flecha en la esquina inferior derecha de la pantalla.</p>
                <p>Cuando termine de escuchar el audio, solo debe esperar 5 segundos y se adelantara solo</p>
                <p>Si desea leer el texto, puede ponerlo en pausa</p>
                </div>
                <span>2 of 100 </span>
            </div>
            <div class ="item">
                <img src=" "/>  
                <div class="caption1"><h1>Audio</h1>
                    <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                    <p>Pueden ver el guin de narracion seleccionado el boton de subtitulos en la barra de navegacion</p>
                    <p>en la parte inferir de la pantalla.</p>
                    <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                    </div>
                    <span>3 of 100</span>
            </div>
            <div class ="item">
                <img src=" "/>  
                <div class="caption1"><h1>Audio</h1>
                    <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                    <p>Pueden ver el guin de narracion seleccionado el boton de subtitulos en la barra de navegacion</p>
                    <p>en la parte inferir de la pantalla.</p>
                    <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                    </div>
                    <span>4 of 100 </span>
            </div>
            <div class ="item">
                <img src=" "/>  
                <div class= "cuadro"></div>
                <div class="caption1"><h1>FINAL</h1>
                    <p>Felicidades por llegar al final.</p>
                    <p>Aqui se te otorgara tu certificado.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="play">Play</span>
            <span class="stop">Stop</span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="un-mute" id="un-mute">
            <label for="un-mute" class="unmute">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg" alt="Mute_Icon.svg" title="Mute icon">
            </label>
            <label for="un-mute" class="mute">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg" alt="Speaker_Icon.svg" title="Unmute/speaker icon">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso, creo que la reproducción automática no va a dar los resultados esperados o va a complicar la lógica por tener que cambiar propiedades cada vez que inicies o pauses.

Ciertamente, no es tan fácil obtener la posición del elemento que se está mostrando, pero puedes "sacarle la vuelta" agregando una propiedad para actualizarla cada que haya cambios.

Los eventos de `Owl Carousel` incluyen la propiedad `event.item.index` con la posición (1 a total de elementos) del elemento que disparó el evento, envías como parámetro a una función donde controlas el tiempo y es lo que vas a usar cuando necesites esta posición, creando la propiedad personalizada `owl.currentIndex = index;`

Vas a tener una reproducción automática, pero controlada por ti mismo, cambiando el tiempo de espera entre cada elemento, de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgItems = $('.item').length; // NUMERO DE SLIDES
    var imgPos = 1;
    var video = document.getElementById('myAudio');
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
    // Temporizador
    var owlTimer;
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        items: 1,
        dots: false,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        nav: true,
        startPosition: 1
    });
    
    // Aplicar tiempo a cada elemento
    function sliderTimeout(index) {
        // Establecer índice actual
        owl.currentIndex = index;
        // Eliminar temporizador actual
        clearTimeout(owlTimer);
        // Obtener elemento actual por índice, jQuery inicia con cero, por eso el -1
        let current = $('.owl-carousel .item').eq(index - 1);
        // Solo si no es el último elemento
        if(index < imgItems) {
            // Definir tiempo por defecto para todos los elementos
            let time = 3000;
            // Aquí puedes analizar el contenido del elemento actual
            // Para elegir audio y duración, cambiando el tiempo de espera
            // Por ejemplo: dar el doble de tiempo para el segundo elemento
            if(index == 2) {
                time = 6000;
            }
            owlTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
            }, time);
        } else {
            // Es el último elemento, puede tener tiempo diferente
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Probablemente quieras usar otra función para terminar
                // Tal vez redirigir a otra página
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
    // Escuchar cambios
    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
        // El índice se obtiene desde el evento
        sliderTimeout(e.item.index);
    });
    
    // Reactivar temporizador
    $('.play').on('click', function() {
        // Reanudar reproducción con el índice guardado previamente
        sliderTimeout(owl.currentIndex);
    });
    // Pausar reproducción
    $('.stop').on('click', function() {
        // Solo es necesario cancelar el temporizador
        clearTimeout(owlTimer);
    });

    // Iniciar reproducción
    sliderTimeout(1);

     /*
    // Esta función no es necesaria, el botón avanza automáticamente
    function nextSlider(){
        if(imgPos >= imgItems){
            imgPos = 1;
            owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplaySpeed',[60000]);
            owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplayTimeout',[60000]);
        }else if(imgPos >= imgItems){
            imgPos++;
        }
    }
    owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

    $('.mute').on('click', function(){
        myAudio.muted = true;

    });
    $('.unmute').on('click', function(){
        myAudio.muted = false;

    });

  
        //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio     
        myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        //Objeto con referencia al boton play
        playBtn = document.getElementById("play");
        //Objeto con referencia al boton pause
        pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pause");
        muteBtn = document.getElementById("mute").muted;
    
    
        //Añadiendo funcionalidad a los botones del reproductor
        playBtn.addEventListener("click", play, true);
        pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", pause, true);
        muteBtn.addEventListener("click", muted);
    */
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class ="slide slide1">
            <img src="img/d7e1725b3801fb6cdeb212884c893f79.jpg"/>   
            <div class="caption">COOPERATIVA VEGA REAL
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class= "item">
            <img src=" "/>  
            <div class="caption1" >
                <video id="myAudio" autoplay controls>
                    <source src="medios/2.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                </video>
                </div>
            <span>1 of 100 </span>
        </div>
        <div class ="item">
            <img src=" "/>
            <div class="caption1"><h1>Sincronización</h1>
            <p>Este entrenamiento durara aproximadamente 45 minutos.</p>
            <p>Puede ver su progreso en la parte inferior de la pantalla</p>
            <p>Puede retroceder una pantalla seleccionando el boton "Atras" en la barra de navegacion.</p>
            <p>para continuar, seleccione el boton de flecha en la esquina inferior derecha de la pantalla.</p>
            <p>Cuando termine de escuchar el audio, solo debe esperar 5 segundos y se adelantara solo</p>
            <p>Si desea leer el texto, puede ponerlo en pausa</p>
            </div>
            <span>2 of 100 </span>
        </div>
        <div class ="item">
            <img src=" "/>  
            <div class="caption1"><h1>Audio</h1>
                <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                <p>Pueden ver el guin de narracion seleccionado el boton de subtitulos en la barra de navegacion</p>
                <p>en la parte inferir de la pantalla.</p>
                <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                </div>
                <span>3 of 100</span>
        </div>
        <div class ="item">
            <img src=" "/>  
            <div class="caption1"><h1>Audio</h1>
                <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                <p>Pueden ver el guin de narracion seleccionado el boton de subtitulos en la barra de navegacion</p>
                <p>en la parte inferir de la pantalla.</p>
                <p>Este entrenamiento tiene audio, incluyendo un narrador y actores de voz.</p>
                </div>
                <span>4 of 100 </span>
        </div>
        <div class ="item">
            <img src=" "/>  
            <div class= "cuadro"></div>
            <div class="caption1"><h1>FINAL</h1>
                <p>Felicidades por llegar al final.</p>
                <p>Aqui se te otorgara tu certificado.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="play">Play</span>
        <span class="stop">Stop</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="un-mute" id="un-mute">
        <label for="un-mute" class="unmute">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Mute_Icon.svg" alt="Mute_Icon.svg" title="Mute icon">
        </label>
        <label for="un-mute" class="mute">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg" alt="Speaker_Icon.svg" title="Unmute/speaker icon">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola!!, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad si me ayudo un montón para lo que quería hacer, pero, crees que para lo de los audios o la narración de los slides, debería hacer un array y navegar en ellos?

Comment: @AlexanderCoronado, sí, creo que es conveniente un arreglo para acceder a los audios, ya tienes el índice y, en ese mismo arreglo, también puedes especificar la duración de cada slide.